# SignalR not serializing NodaTime types despite JsonSerializer settings

Tags: serialization, json.net, signalr, nodatime

I am having serialization issues (exceptions) with NodaTime types and SignalR parameters such as

```
Error converting value to type 'NodaTime.ZonedDateTime

Error converting value \"2016-06-01T18:33:36.7279685+01 Europe/London\" to type 'NodaTime.ZonedDateTime'. Path '[0].DateCreated', line 1, position 79.
```

This is despite following the [docs](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility) and replacing the default JsonSerializer and using the NodaTime extension methods and JSON.net nuget package e.g.

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings js = new JsonSerializerSettings();
js.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(js);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Happily found a workaround from [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3304) thanks to [BrannonKing](https://github.com/BrannonKing)

Essentially it uses a Customer Resolver for SignalR parameters which uses the correct serializer instead of creating a default.

Also referenced on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952406/signalr-dont-resolve-jsonserializer-for-incoming-server-call) but of course only found that once had started to post my own question ;)

Reposting here for others googling for (the excellent) [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) specifically, and to share some other serialization fixes I needed, such as :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property X with type Y Path Z
```

**Server Startup**

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings js = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    js.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
    js.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
    js.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
    js.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(js);
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
    var resolver = new Resolver(serializer);
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IParameterResolver), () => resolver);
}
```

**Custom Parameter Resolver**

```cs
public class Resolver : DefaultParameterResolver
    {
        private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

        public Resolver(JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            _serializer = serializer;
        }

        private FieldInfo _valueField;
        public override object ResolveParameter(ParameterDescriptor descriptor, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.IJsonValue value)
        {
            if(value.GetType() == descriptor.ParameterType)
            {
                return value;
            }

            if(_valueField == null)
                _valueField = value.GetType().GetField("_value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            var json = (string)_valueField.GetValue(value);
            using(var reader = new StringReader(json))
                return _serializer.Deserialize(reader, descriptor.ParameterType);
        }
    }
```

Many thanks Brannon !